# What's the word for something that is 'good', but 'bad' at the same time?

Tags: single-word-requests

What is the **word** that describes an act that was meant to be an act of kindness/helpful, but ironically has not been helpful at all.

I know the word, but it's totally gone out of my head, and I cannot for the life of me remember it.

A few examples:

- > Hanging out the washing for someone trying to do them a favour, but hanging it incorrectly so it's not going to dry that well.
- > Doing the dishes for Mum after she's cooked you tea, but you put something non dish washer safe in the dish washer.
- > Mowing the lawns for your Grandma, but the mower was too short and has now killed the grass.
- > You told your wife you'd do the washing for her, which she was so thankful for, but you put the towels in with the clothes, and she
  >   wasn't too happy about that.

I KNOW there is a word, but I just am absolutely stumped. Any help?!

Comment: "Well-intentioned" is one possibility.

Comment: Hmmm I see where you're coming from and it is along those lines, but that wasn't the word it was, thank you though

Comment: How about "well-meaning"?

Comment: Hmm also along the same lines, but not the word I was after, I think it was a single word.

Comment: Are you looking for *counterproductive?*

Comment: 'Backfire': "I mowed the lawn for granny, but my helpfulness backfired because the mower was set too short and the grass died." If not that, can you supply a sentence where the missing word is indicated with, for example, underlining (_______)?

Comment: "Goodwill" is a possibility, but doesn't necessarily imply a mistake or a failure. In that respect, I prefer "well-intentionned".

Comment: "The best of intentions..."

Comment: Ahhh I'll never find this word :'(. It's a word defining the action of what happened. It's a word for the action itself. It is along the line of backfired, but to say something backfired, it's more of a verb, my original word I knew was an adjective, one word that described the situation.

Comment: @George, *bungle* or a synonym?

Comment: A possible one word solution, might be [counterproductive](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/counterproductive) otherwise *mixed blessings* suggests that something was good and bad simultaneously.

Answer (score 0):

I also have the feeling that there is a single word that perfectly fits this meaning. I don't think this is it but it might suit you:
maybe...**backfired**?

*I was trying to do something nice for my Mom but the whole thing backfired.*

Comment: from miriam webster: **Boomerang**- an act or utterance that backfires on its originator

Comment: This is close, but not the answer, I don't know how this has been voted as the answer

Answer (score 0):

This might be stronger than you intended:

"**Kill them with kindness** implies that by being kind, you purposely or inadvertently *annoy, exact revenge, irritate* or encourage a particular behavior in a person. People often use this method of conflict resolution when they feel frustrated by other attempts to resolve an issue, feel powerless in a situation, don't know how to express difficult emotions or they want to avoid pressuring overtly."

Read more : http://www.ehow.com/info_8433153_ways-kill-someone-kindness.html